# Board Game Design in Cocos2d

Tags: frameworks, cocos2d-iphone

i am going to start a chess like board game. and for that i have reviewed a number to things available.

one is http://www.mapeditor.org/ , using which you can create a grid base games.

another option is geekgameboard for iphone available at http://mooseyard.lighthouseapp.com/projects/23201-geekgameboard

now i want your expert opinion that would it be better to make a game in cocos2d using the first option or the second option?
both looks promising to me and give good control over board design.

Comment: forget to mention that i also posted the same question on cocos2d forum, so i will cross notify any interesting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use elements of either, but neither of them (or cocos2d) are instant board game design tools.

GeekGameBoard is a demo of Core Animation and (to a lesser extent) Objective-C. There are many things you will learn from it but little of the graphic parts are applicable to a cocos2d project. If you hadn't already figured that out then you need to read more widely to understand exactly what cocos2d is, and how it compares to using Core Animation.

As taintedzodiac says, Tiled is simply a map editor. I do think there are board games that would benefit from this (although all the examples I can think of would need hexagons) but I expect that a chess-like game involves a board that will always fit on the screen, so you've probably not got much need for Tiled.

I would suggest that you

1) Design the board on paper and playtest your game design in the real world if you haven't already.

2) Try implementing the game in GeekGameBoard (without cocos2d).

3) Using the knowledge gained from that experience, rewrite it in cocos2d using what you can from the GeekGameBoard implementation.

Comment: i have gone on the same way , first implement in geekgameboard because it gives you great framework related to board and let you concentrate on game logic. then rewrite it in cocos2d.   now can you tell it is possible to implement game logic in geekgameboard but use the cocos2d for scene management and menu's related work?

Answer (score 1):

Tiled is simply a map editor. You cannot use it to implement actual game logic.

I have no experience with geekgameboard, but it seems like a very specialized framework that may work well for what you are describing. That being said, cocos2d is probably much more versatile than geekgameboard, so you may or may not be reinventing the wheel more often than you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Tabletop Simulator: https://www.tabletopsimulator.com/

It's a board game simulator, which would allow you to test the rules of the game first, and then add scripts to actually implement them.
This way you can get to a playable version of your game inside the simulator pretty fast, and prototype your ideas

This will give you a good base to decide whether you should start writing your own game framework (most of the time this is not a great idea), or if you should use something like Godot or Unity as a base to build your game.

I'd recommend to either use the Tableetop Simulator or a pen&paper version of the game to get a grasp of all the rules, and then go over the basic unity tutorials (to get a general idea of the tool) and then dive into more specific topics that directly translate into your game after that.